# Counter of submitted forms in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to make a counter for submitting a form in php, if the data from the forms is sent to the server, `+1 is written to the counter.txt file`, this data is used to form the header in the letter. Everything works, but `5 identical letters come to the mail, the next time it sends 10 and so on`. What is the problem? Why is this happening?
When I remove the counter code everything works fine and one letter arrives.

```
  <?php


$email = ($_POST['sel']);
$change = ($_POST['button-set']);
$name = ($_POST['name']);
$question = ($_POST['message']);
$submit = ($_POST['submit']); 

if (isset ($submit)) {
    $count = file_get_contents ('counter.txt');
    $count ++;
    file_put_contents ('counter.txt', $count);
}
else {
    $count = file_get_contents ('counter.txt');
};

$to = 'support@archsupport.ru'; 
$subject = 'Application number: ' . $count . 'from the site archsupport.ru';  
$message = 'Name: ' . $name . "\r\n" . 'Contacts: ' . $email . "\r\n" . 'Write ' . $change . "\r\n" . 'Question: ' . $question  ; 
$headers = 'From: zergg52@gmail.com ' . "\r\n";
$subject = preg_replace("/(\r\n)|(\r)|(\n)/", "", $subject);
$subject = preg_replace("/(\t)/", " ", $subject);
$subject = '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . '?=';
@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo 'message sent!';
var_dump($email,$change,$name,$question,$submit,$count)
?>
```

Page code:

```js
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
var names = document.getElementById('name');
var validn = document.getElementById('vn');
var iconrequired = document.querySelector('#namereq');
var email = document.getElementById('sellection');
var valids = document.getElementById('vs');
var iconrequireds = document.querySelector('#sellectionreq');
var text = document.getElementById('qestions');
var validt = document.getElementById('vt');
var iconrequiredt = document.querySelector('#textreq');


document.addEventListener('input', function validation() {

  var x = document.forms["support"]["sellection"].value;


  if (names.validity.valid) {
    validn.className = "valid";
    iconrequired.className = "iconrequired hide";

  };

  if (email.validity.valid && x != "") {

    valids.className = "valid";
    iconrequireds.className = "iconrequired hide";

  };
  if (text.validity.valid) {
    validt.className = "valid";
    iconrequiredt.className = "iconrequired hide";

  };
  if (!names.validity.valid) {
    validn.className = "invalid";
    iconrequired.className = "iconrequired hide";

  };
  if (!email.validity.valid) {
    valids.className = "invalid";
    iconrequireds.className = "iconrequired hide";

  };

  if (!text.validity.valid) {
    validt.className = "invalid";
    iconrequiredt.className = "iconrequired hide";

  };

  if (names.validity.valid && email.validity.valid && text.validity.valid) {

    $('#support').submit(function() {

      $.post(
        'https://www.archsupport.ru/post-email.php',
        $("#support").serialize(),

        function(msg) {
          $('#support').hide('slow');
          $('#message').html(msg);
        }
      );


    });


  } else {

    return false;

  }
});





function validateSellection() {
  var x = document.forms["support"]["sellection"].value;
  if (x === "") {
    document.getElementById('sellectionreq').classList.remove("hide");
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('sellectionreq').classList.add("hide");
    return false;
  }
};

function validateName() {
  var x = document.forms["support"]["name"].value;
  if (x === "") {
    document.getElementById('namereq').classList.remove("hide");
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('namereq').classList.add("hide");
    return false;
  }
};

function validateText() {
  var x = document.forms["support"]["qestions"].value;
  if (x === "") {
    document.getElementById('textreq').classList.remove("hide");
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('textreq').classList.add("hide");
    return false;
  }
};

$('#support').submit(function validate() {
  if (validateName() && validateSellection() && validateText() === true) {

    return false;
  } else {

    validateSellection();
    validateName();
    validateText()
    return false

  }
});



$(".radio").on('click.two', function() {
  let input = $("#sellection");
  if ($("#radio").prop("checked")) {
    input.prop("disabled", false);
    input.prop({
      "type": "email",
      "placeholder": "example@yourmail.ru",
      "autocomplete": "email",
      "maxlength": "35",
      "minlength": "12",
      "value": "",
    });
    document.getElementById("sellection").pattern = "^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$";
  } else {
    input.prop("disabled", false);
    $("#sellection").prop({
      "type": "tel",
      "placeholder": "+7-910-205-46-15",
      "autocomplete": "tel",
      "maxlength": "16",
      "minlength": "11",
      "value": "",
    });
    document.getElementById("sellection").pattern = "\\+7\\s?[\\(]{0,1}9[0-9]{2}[\\)]{0,1}\\s?\\d{3}[-]{0,1}\\d{2}[-]{0,1}\\d{2}";
  }
  input.focus();
  input.val("");
});

var fab = $('.icons');
fab.on('click.ten', function iconback() {
  fab.removeClass('checked');
  $(this).addClass('checked');
});
```

```css
@keyframes req {
  0% {
    transform: translatex(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translatex(5px);
  }
}

@keyframes inv {
  0% {
    opacity: .5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

:root {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr";
  font-weight: 100;
}

form {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

textarea {
  height: 30vh;
  border-radius: 18px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  outline: none;
  resize: none
}

input,
textarea {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr";
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 18px;
}

 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 18px;
}

 ::-moz-placeholder {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* Firefox 19+ */

 :-moz-placeholder {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* Firefox 18- */

 :-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 18px;
}

input:not([type="submit"]) {
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 36px;
  border: none;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #f3f3f3;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: white;
  padding-left: 13px;
}

.required {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.iconrequired {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 90px;
  height: 14px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr";
  background: #343434;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity ease-out 1s;
  animation: .05s ease-in-out 0s 4 alternate req;
}

input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
  border: 2px solid #f3f3f3;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 13px;
}

div.button-set {
  display: inline-flex;
}

div.button-set>label {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.checked {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr";
  height: 36px;
  width: 160px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  padding: 0;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 5px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  display: none;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: transparent;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  z-index: 9999;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: transparent;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
}

.invalid {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 12px;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 6px;
  animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate inv;
}

.valid {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 12px;
  background: #9dc46b;
  border-radius: 6px;
  animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate inv;
}

.error {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: gray;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/form.css">
</head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <form novalidate action="" method="post" name="support" id="support">
    <label class="required"><span id="vs" class="invalid hide"></span><input id="sellection" class="mail sellection" name="sel" vlaue="" placeholder="choose a communication way...."  required disabled><span id="error1"></span><div id="sellectionreq" class="iconrequired hide">REQUIRED</div></label>
    <div class="button-set">
      <label title="Email"><img class="icons" src='/img/icon/social_icon_mail_white.svg'><input class="radio" id="radio" type="radio" name="button-set" value="to mail" style="display:none;"></label>

      <label for="radio1" title="WhatsApp"><img class="icons" src='/img/icon/social_icon_whatsapp_white.svg'><input class="radio" id="radio1" type="radio" name="button-set" value="to WhatsApp" style="display:none;"></label>

      <label for="radio2" title="Telegram"><img class="icons" src='/img/icon/social_icon_telegram_white.svg'><input class="radio" id="radio2" type="radio" name="button-set" value="to Telegram" style="display:none;"></label>

      <label for="radio3" title="Viber"><img class="icons" src='/img/icon/social_icon_viber_white.svg'><input class="radio" id="radio3" type="radio" name="button-set" value="to Viber" style="display:none;"></label>
    </div>
    <label class="required"><span id="vn" class="invalid hide"></span>
   <input id="name" class="mail" type="name" name="name" autocomplete= none placeholder="what's your name...." value="" pattern="[A-Za-z]+(\s+[A-Za-z]+)?" maxlength="15" minlength="2" required><div id="namereq" class="iconrequired hide">REQUIRED</div></label>
    <label class="required"><span id="vt" class="invalid hide"></span><textarea id="qestions" type="text" placeholder="your question...." name="message" value="" pattern="[A-Za-z]+(\s+[A-Za-z]+)?" maxlength="400" minlength="4" required></textarea><div id="textreq" class="iconrequired hide">REQUIRED</div></label>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
  </form>
  <div id="message"></div>
</body>
<script src="/js/form.js"></script>

</html>
```

without counter:

> var_dump($email,$change,$name,$question,$submit) - string(12)
>   "+79102054615" string(11) "to WhatsApp" string(4) "ZERG" string(8)
>   "ANYTHING" NULL

with counter:

> var_dump($email,$change,$name,$question,$submit,$count) - string(12)
>   "+79102054615" string(11) "to WhatsApp" string(4) "ZERG" string(8)
>   "ANYTHING" NULL string(1) "9"

$count immediately takes on value "9"

site with form: https://www.archsupport.ru/

Comment: Well your script throws tons of fatal errors when I run it online. It is because of this weird formatting (not sure if this is the same code you run on the server because it does not work). Just write ´$var´ not ´$  var´ and don't put spaces in between ´$ _ POST´etc. After the else you can delete the semicolon. Don't you need to check $_POST['f'] first before you access it? I fixed it and at least I got no errors anymore. file_get_contents returns the file as a string - only if the content is numeric php will convert it to an int (tested in php 7). Also you should rather use a database.

Comment: @F.Müller Yes, of course, something is wrong with the formatting, I did not notice that everything is fine with the server, the problem is not that

Comment: use var_dump() to inspect the email params before you use it here @mail(...) once with counter the other one without - try to find differences. Hard to tell from this point of view. You may want to update the code you posted here (its messy and hard to debug). I would need to see the debug outputs to find the bug.

Comment: @F.Müller  thank you man, for me it is all very difficult, I do it for the first time, so my code is so bad

Comment: @F.Müller updated according to your requirements, apparently the case in JS

Comment: The form Is submitted more times than one? Inspect the inspector network Tab to see how many request are made. The problem should be on JS.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the HTML/JavaScript, consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  var form = $("#support");

  function checkFieldValidity(fObj) {
    var r = false;
    var re = new RegExp(fObj.attr("pattern"));
    var v = fObj.val();
    if (fObj.is("[required]")) {
      if (v.length) {
        fObj.next(".iconrequired").hide();
      } else {
        fObj.next(".iconrequired").show();
      }
      if (re.test(v)) {
        fObj.prev(".icon").removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
        r = true;
      } else {
        fObj.prev(".icon").removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
      }
    } else {
      r = true;
    }
    return r;
  }

  $("input", form).blur(function() {
    checkFieldValidity($(this));
  });

  form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var valid = true;
    $("[required]", form).each(function(i, el) {
      valid = valid && checkFieldValidity($(el));
    });
    return valid;
  });

  $(".button-set label", form).on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".checked").removeClass("checked");
    $("img", this).addClass("checked");
    var input = $("#sellection");
    input.prop("disabled", false);
    switch ($(this).data("value")) {
      case "email":
        input.prop({
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "example@yourmail.com",
          autocomplete: "email",
          maxlength: 35,
          minlength: 12,
          value: "",
        }).attr("pattern", "^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$");
        break;
        // Add Cases for each selection option if needed
      default:
        input.prop({
          "type": "tel",
          "placeholder": "+7-910-205-46-15",
          "autocomplete": "tel",
          "maxlength": "16",
          "minlength": "11",
          "value": "",
        });
        input.attr("pattern", "\\+7\\s?[\\(]{0,1}9[0-9]{2}[\\)]{0,1}\\s?\\d{3}[-]{0,1}\\d{2}[-]{0,1}\\d{2}");
        break;
    }
    input.focus();
    input.val("");
  });
});
```

```css
@keyframes req {
  0% {
    transform: translatex(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translatex(5px);
  }
}

@keyframes inv {
  0% {
    opacity: .5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

:root {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr";
  font-weight: 100;
}

form {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

textarea {
  height: 30vh;
  border-radius: 18px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  outline: none;
  resize: none
}

input,
textarea {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr";
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 18px;
}

 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 18px;
}

 ::-moz-placeholder {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* Firefox 19+ */

 :-moz-placeholder {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* Firefox 18- */

 :-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 18px;
}

input:not([type="submit"]) {
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 36px;
  border: none;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #f3f3f3;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: white;
  padding-left: 13px;
}

.required {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.iconrequired {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 90px;
  height: 14px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr";
  background: #343434;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity ease-out 1s;
  animation: .05s ease-in-out 0s 4 alternate req;
}

input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
  border: 2px solid #f3f3f3;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 13px;
}

div.button-set {
  display: inline-flex;
}

div.button-set>label {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.checked {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueCyr";
  height: 36px;
  width: 160px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  padding: 0;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 5px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  display: none;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: transparent;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  z-index: 9999;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: transparent;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
}

.invalid {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 12px;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 6px;
  animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate inv;
}

.valid {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 12px;
  background: #9dc46b;
  border-radius: 6px;
  animation: 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate inv;
}

.error {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: gray;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form novalidate action="" method="post" name="support" id="support">
  <span class="icon"></span><input id="sellection" class="mail" name="f[sel]" value="" placeholder="Choose a communication method...." required disabled>
  <div class="iconrequired hide">REQUIRED</div>
  <div class="button-set">
    <label title="Email" data-value="email"><img class="icon" src='/img/icon/social_icon_mail_white.svg'></label>
    <label title="WhatsApp" data-value="whatsapp"><img class="icon" src='/img/icon/social_icon_whatsapp_white.svg'></label>
    <label title="Telegram" data-value="telegram"><img class="icon" src='/img/icon/social_icon_telegram_white.svg'></label>
    <label title="Viber" data-value="viber"><img class="icon" src='/img/icon/social_icon_viber_white.svg'></label>
  </div>
  <label class="required"><span class="icon"></span>
   <input id="name" class="mail" type="name" name="f[name]" autocomplete="none" placeholder="what's your name...." value="" pattern="[A-Za-z]+(\s+[A-Za-z]+)?" maxlength="15" minlength="2" required><div id="namereq" class="iconrequired hide">REQUIRED</div></label>
  <label class="required"><span id="vt" class="invalid hide"></span><textarea id="qestions" type="text" placeholder="your question...." name="f[message]" value="" pattern="[A-Za-z]+(\s+[A-Za-z]+)?" maxlength="400" minlength="45" required></textarea><div id="textreq" class="iconrequired hide">REQUIRED</div></label>
  <input name="f[submit]" type="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
<div id="message"></div>
```

You want to evaluate if each field that is required has content and matches a specific pattern. I think your approach was too complicated. Additionally, I would stick with all native JavaScript or all jQuery. Don't mix them.

For `submit`, you will want to test each field and keep a running tally. To do this, you can logically start with a `true` value and as you test, keep logically evaluating. Example:

```
var result = true;
result = result && true; // result is true
result = result && false; // result is false
result = result && true; // result is false
```

If some of the fields validate and if any do not, the result will be `false` and the form should not submit. If all validate, the result will be `true` and it's safe to submit the data to PHP. This should also prevent multiple submissions.

Remember that this is Client Side validation and can be bypassed by posting the data manually to the PHP. Most users will not even bother, yet all it takes is one curious or malicious User or Bot to see that they can bypass the form and create their own HTTP Post Payload. So you will want to ensure that your PHP is protected from such actions. Test any data submitted by the User before using it in your PHP Code. For example, you define `$name` like so:

```
$name = ($_POST['name']);
```

If I construct a payload like:

```
&name=;include "/etc/passwd";
```

This might get evaluated in the following code:

$message = 'Name: ' . $name . "\r\n" . 'Contacts: ' . $email . "\r\n" . 'Write ' . $change . "\r\n" . 'Question: ' . $question;

Just some things to consider.